# Leaving work gracefully

Tags: resignation, ethics, notice-period

I work for a large corporation and within it there are multiple projects on going at any one time. Usually, you get to know the people that you work with on projects and they sort of become close based on their relationship to you.

I am planning on leaving my job but my job has plans to hold training and other things to bring up the engineers ready for the rest of the year. On one hand, as an employee, I have a duty to be trained and use the information I am being taught for future engineers and also future work but on the other hand my manager might do better without me and train someone else who isn't going to throw a two weeks notice in their face.

I haven’t made the decision when that will be but it will be soon. In a situation like this do I just shut up and not say anything or inform him of my plans? Part of this is also because they will be flying us out – I just feel like what a waste of company funds but on the other hand nothing is set in stone. They always say don't let anyone know at your job if you are leaving as this can make work life difficult. What do I do?

Comment: see also: [How can I ethically “ease into” quitting a job?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/114640/168)

Comment: Hi LeanMan - this topic is covered very thoroughly by a number of existing questions. You can look at the two links @gnat posted for starters, and there are many more close duplicates linked in the comments and related sections of those questions. Unless you can edit your question and show how it is substantially different from those existing questions, it should probably be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 13):

> *They always say don't let anyone know at your job if you are leaving as this can make work life difficult.*

Thank them, they are right.

Continue as usual, until it's time to submit your resignation (i.e., you have a confirmed offer with you) and then, serve the notice period and leave. **Till then, continue as usual,** including accepting the salary, promotion, training etc.

Comment: As "selfish" as this may seem, this is the best way to go about it from an employee perspective. While some employers may be much more receptive to working with you through transition period, ensuring both sides part fairly, you don't know if that's your company until you tell them. And then it can get ugly if they are not so cooperative.

Comment: Yes, you need to be selfish here.  The company isn't going to cut you any slack when it comes time for cutbacks; they're going to do what's in the best interest of the company (or what HR thinks is in the best interest).  You need to think of yourself as a company of one person and one (maybe more) shareholders, and act in the best interest of those stakeholders.

Comment: Even if they are nice, they may end up doing what is best for the company and their budget. It's always a good idea to actually have a job and you're ready to leave in case.

Answer (score 7):

Until you have handed in your notice, you are still working there and you should continue working there as normal - including taking any training you are asked to (so long as there are no strings attached with repayment etc.)

The reality is, you do not know for certain that you will leave shortly - until you have actually tendered your notice.

Perhaps the job search goes badly, perhaps something happens in your personal life that means you have to stick out with this job for longer than planned. Either way, announcing your intention to leave before you actually give the notice does nothing beneficial for you, it simply limits your options.

Worth remembering is that from an employer side, there is never a good time to have a good employee leave. Going just after training, going in the middle of a major project, or just after a new junior is hired - all of these are simply risks an employer needs to deal with, and you shouldn't expect any particular consequence for the timing of your departure.

Answer (score 0):

Might need to put in a location but generally speaking in USA at-will worker the "graceful" thing to do is give a 2 weeks notice. For contracts and otherwise, you might need to give a more advanced notice.

Generally a bad idea to tell the boss you're going to quit unless you already have a job on hand and ready to leave. They may let you go, even though you're both on good terms.